# I want to break my monolithic to microservices but I'm still stuck on it. Need advise

Tags: architecture, microservices

So far, my developing application is planned to be available on web and mobile so I decided to do it as microservice.

What my app can do so far is listed below:

- Sign up (email, username, password, password_confirmation)
- Sign in (email, password)
- Sign in using Facebook (automatically sign in if email is exist in db, or create new record then automatically sign in when email is not exist in db)
- View articles
- Post articles
- Edit articles
- Delete articles

As actions above, **how many services should I break into**? *I'm not sure to split every actions in to service like sign-up-service / sign-in-service or group it up as user-service is the right way.*

An another question, **when I split services separately how can I get articles data with the authors to render on my sites?** *Build new broker service which get articles data within article-service then get author data within user-service after that*? Or, broker service is no needed, just simply get articles data then author data in my web-application controller.

Comment: its a broad question to answer, i would suggest read about DDD( Domain Driven Design) concepts and try to apply with micro service architecture. Just so that you know going the micro service route is not a success always, there are many factors to consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So far, my developing application is planned to be available on web and mobile so I decided to do it as microservice.

Choosing microservice (MS) approach based on the fact that your application will support more than one platform is not advisable. If you have never before dealt with microservice architecture, it is perhaps better to build a modular monolith with strong context boundaries. This way it will be easier to focus on programming and implementing application, and later on you can gradually break down monolith into microservices, one at a time (i. e. you start with modules that have low traffic, like sign up service). Also, going straight to microservices, except if you are doing a project for your own experience or fun, suits into category of premature optimization. For more info about Monolith first approach, Martin Fowler wrote a [great article](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/MonolithFirst.html) about it.

> As actions above, how many services should I break into?

[I am answering in context of splitting backend system and calling MS from frontend via API.]
Sign up and sign in should be a different service, as generally sign up is used less frequently (once a user signs up, he just signs in from now on) than sign in. Facebook sign in would go with sign in MS. 
Viewing articles is also more frequent than posting, editing or deleting (either you have a blog platform or Facebook), so one MS would provide data to view articles, and one MS would be used to post, edit or delete articles.

> when I split services separately how can I get articles data with the authors to render on my sites?

Most adviced approach with MS artchitecture is polyglot persistence, where every MS would have its own database, containing the tables it actually edits or updates. Then you can take approach of accessing data of other MS through calling its APIs (view article service has, in its Article table, also ID of author, then you call user service/sign up service with ID of author to get its full info), though this provides more tightly coupled architecture.

Another option is to store data in form of events, where new user registering is an event, that gets stored in user service MS database and sent to some queue or topic, and other services can register to receive events from it and store the events in their database. This way you will duplicate data, but will have more loosely coupled (and asynchronous) architecture. Google event driven data management for more on this approach.